# can I perform a query inside of JPA entity to get back a single column

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I have a dumb question.  It would be great if this could be done, but I am not holding my breath.

I need a single column from a table linked to my JPA entity to be a collection in said JPA entity.  Is there any way, that I can just get back that column alone that is related to that entity, instead of having to get back an entire table (which could be very costly?)

Can I perform a query inside that JPA entity that will be performed and loaded eagerly into a collection?

I am trying to avoid having to make several calls to the database by just executing a couple of queries.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Have you tried `select e.collectionField from Entity e`? Why not test it?

Comment: close... I just figured it out.  Ill post the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @CollectionTable(name="QUICK_LAUNCH_DISTLIST",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="QUICK_LAUNCH_ID"))
        @Column(name="LIST_ID")
private List<Long> distListIDs;
```

The ElementCollection attribute is what I was looking for.  It seems to work pretty well in addition to that.

Thanks for the help and inspiration guys.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a Category has many products:

```
select product.name from Category c inner join c.products product where ...
```

If that's not what you want, please show an example in your question.